# How to correct the comment in Makefile? "mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax"

Tags: c, linux, module, makefile

My `Makefile` definition is as follows:-

```
TARGET = wfirewall
obj-m = $(TARGET).o

KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)
default:
    make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean :
    rm -f $(TARGET).ko $(TARGET).o $(TARGET).mod.*
```

I am getting the message

```
root@debian:/firewall# make
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-586/build SUBDIRS=/firewall modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-586'
Makefile:10: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-586'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-586'
```

look at that!! mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax???
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Which line is line 10 ? Anyway you should write 'clean:' instead of 'clean :'. Just remove the space.

Comment: Sounds like there is a separate `Makefile` in `/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-586/build` which you are not showing us.  Please [edit] your question to include the pertinent information.

Comment: Thank you TimF! I correted it! and tripleee do you mean can i show you /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-586/build/Makefile ?? it is..
  1 VERSION = 2
  2 PATCHLEVEL = 6
  3 MAKEARGS := -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common O=/usr/src/linux-heade    rs-3.16.0-4-586
  4 MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory
  5 .PHONY: all $(MAKECMDGOALS)
  6 cmd := $(filter-out all Makefile,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
  7 all:
  8     @$(MAKE) $(MAKEARGS) $(cmd)
  9 Makefile:;
 10 $(cmd) %/: all
 11     @:

it's right??

Comment: oh!!! i solved my problem!! 
in  /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-586/build/Makefile
i correct  following syntax
$(cmd) %/: all   -> $(cmd) : all
but i can't understand that's why???

Comment: It's hard to see the structure of the Makefile in the comments but maybe if you edit your original post with the line that was the problem and the line fixed I will be able to explain why it was a problem.

Comment: <pre> 
VERSION = 2 
PATCHLEVEL = 6 
MAKEARGS := -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common O=/usr/src/linux-heade rs-3.16.0-4-586 
MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory
.PHONY: all $(MAKECMDGOALS) 
cmd := $(filter-out all Makefile,$(MAKECMDGOALS)) 
all: 
@$(MAKE) $(MAKEARGS) $(cmd) 
Makefile:; 
$(cmd) %/: all 
@:
</pre>